# Making vue-awesome work with Nuxt

Tags: vue.js, webpack-2

I am trying to make `vue-awesome` work with my [Nuxt](https://github.com/nuxt) project.

I modified my **nuxt.config.js** with this

```
vendor: ['vue-awesome']
```

I did this in my **default.vue**

```
import Icon from 'vue-awesome';

export default {
    components: {
        Icon
    }
}
```

But this gives me an error

> window is not defined

---

Then I tried removing the import from **default.vue** and just use it in my page.
The component's code is there in the chrome dev tools, but the icon is not visible, do I need to modify my webpack configuration or something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer has been answered on the [official repository](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/174#issuecomment-275939000).

You need to use the nuxt [plugins](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/174) to register the component as global.

Example:

`nuxt.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
  build: {
    vendor: ['vue-awesome']
  },
  plugins: ['~plugins/vue-awesome.js']
}
```

`plugins/vue-awesome.js`

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Icon from 'vue-awesome/components/Icon.vue'
require('vue-awesome/icons')

Vue.component('icon', Icon)
```

Then in your pages and components, you can use the  component:

`pages/index.vue`

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>Welcome!</h1>
    <icon name="camera"></icon>
  </div>
</template>
```